# Editing textboxes in a partial view and making them react if there is a change

Tags: jquery

I have html that looks like this

```
            <tr class="inv pastdue">
            <td class="amount-due">327.79</td>
            <td class="pmnt-amount">
            <input id="PaymentAmount" name="PaymentAmount" type="text" value="327.79" class="valid">
            </td>
            </tr>
```

Jquery that looks like this

```
            $(function () {
                        var amountDue = $('#amount-due').val();
                        $('#PaymentAmount').keyup(function () {
                            if ($('#PaymentAmount').val() != amountDue) {
                                //do something
                                alert('Content has been changed');
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

If I change the amount it works i.e the alert fires

If I put back the change I made making both of them the same again, the alert fires.(This 
is wrong. Since they are the same alert should not fire)

When I change other rows with textboxes nothing happens. The jquery only affects row 1 and I have multiple rows with editable textboxes

Here is what I want to achieve

1. If I edit the PaymentAmount text box and its not the same with amount-due fire alert
2. If I put back the same amount and two are the same, do not fire alert
3. jquery should affect other rows that have textboxes. I want to be able to edit them.

Comment: add amoundDue=$('#amount-due').val(); after alert

Comment: you don't you dynamically create id such as PaymentAmount1, PaymentAmount2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is your selector and for a TD it should be `.text()` because td don't have values:

```
 var amountDue = $('#amount-due').val(); <-- selecting an id
```

In your HTML you have amount-due as a class (be warned if you have multiple with that class and you use a selector you may not get the right element):

```
<td class="amount-due">327.79</td>
```

Change your selector to:

```
 var amountDue = $('.amount-due').text();
```

I would suggest using blur instead of key up. Its a poor user experience to have an alert they have to dismiss every keystroke. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wu3WP/11/)

**UPDATE FROM COMMENTS (Misunderstood first comment sorry)**

First off add a class to your inputs then. The id attribute is meant to be unique per page.

```
<input id="PaymentAmount" class="payment-amount" name="PaymentAmount" type="text" value="327.79" class="valid">
```

Then change your `blur` selector to be `$(".payment-amount").blur(...)`

You'll have to change how you get the amount due to compare with you can see it in the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wu3WP/22/)

Comment: Thanks. This works for just one row. I have multiple rows. How will this work for multiple rows i.e changing the values of the text boxes

Comment: @user2320476 so you will have multiple PaymentAmount inputs? and you want to update those with the value entered?

Comment: Yes I will have multiple PaymentAmount inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem I encountered with your recent code is if you change a value of a textbox, all the other textboxes change. I will need to have different values for each textbox.

Comment: I guess I am confused. So when I enter a value into the Payment Amount what gets updated?

Comment: Only the textbox you update should be updated. The other ones should not be affected